# Google cloud PubSub keeps throwing timeout error on production

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, networking, google-cloud-pubsub

It's my first time using google pubsub on production. We are using the Python client and deploying projects with docker and k8s. The code snippet is just as the sample code provided by google.

```py
    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = config["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]
    project_id = "abc"
    topic_id = "asd"
    self._publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
    self._topic_path = self._publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_id)
    log_info_json = json.dumps({"id": 1})
    publish_future = self._publisher.publish(self._topic_path, log_info_json.encode("utf-8"))
    publish_future.result(timeout=5)
```

The code works fine locally, however, the k8s cluster has network constraints and I think this is the reason why we keep getting `TimeoutError` when we try on production. I have already made `*.googleapis.com` and `*.google.com` accessible but the error still exists. I have already tried to access the pod and ensure that all the links in the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` json file are accessible.

Comment: Could you provide full error message you are getting? Can you try including credentials as `import os os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "path_to_your_.json_credential_file"` ?

Comment: after spending days and nights together with my company's network team, we fix the issue but still don't know what's going on. We tried to use API calls instead of the client library and find out that, first, our network is extremely unstable for some reason, second, if we use client library it will just hang there forever, so we proceed to use API call and suggest u trying it if encountered the same issue

Answer (score 1):

@DYX, As you have mentioned in the comment, this issue was because of an unstable network and when using the client library it just hangs there forever.

This issue was resolved using [API call](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest) instead of the client library.

If the issue persists, if you have a support plan you can create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.